# Python breaking filter running after filnd the answer

Tags: python

Can I stop filter if it find the answer?, For example it find the number 10.

example:

```
filter(lambda num:num == 10,range(20))
```

Comment: [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=comprehension#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) are two different things, please update your question with a relevant example

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What type of filter did you speak? That question is broad

Comment: print filter(lambda num:num == 10,range(20))

Comment: What is the meaning of: *it contains 2 number*?

Comment: Your question is strange, filter is used to select elements that meet certain conditions. Please give an appropriate context to your question?

Comment: I want to find the number 10 within a list of 1-20. After I find the 10 stop running the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of stopping an iteration early using `filter` by setting a global flag that causes the filter function to raise `StopIteration`:

```
def my_filter(n):
    """ filter for odd numbers """

    if my_flag:
        raise StopIteration

    return n % 2 == 1

my_flag = False

for my_number in filter(my_filter, range(1, 22)):

    print(my_number)

    if my_number % 13 == 0:
        my_flag = True
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
>
```

Is this what you have in mind?  But, of course, most people would simply do:

```
if my_number % 13 == 0:
        break
```

So you must have some specific scenario in mind.  (Hopefully something more than, "Because I want it to be a one line comprehension.")